# react native import fonts

Tags: android, react-native, fonts

I am trying to add fonts to my Project.
i added it like [Here](https://github.com/rnpm/rnpm#advanced-usage) recomended

**1.)** added to Package.json

#### Package.json:

```
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
     ]
   }
```

**2.)** added files

assets\fonts\Roboto.ttf

assets\fonts\vincHand.ttf

**3.)** Linked everything

```
 rnpm link
```

**4.)** added code to my Project

```
      <Text> Test </Text>
      <Text style={{ fontFamily: "Roboto" }}> Test </Text>
      <Text style={{ fontFamily: "vincHand" }}> Test </Text>
```

**5.)** rebuild app

```
react-native.cmd run-android
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### Question

why are the fonts not displayed and all 3 text with the default-Font?

Comment: use 'react-native link' command  in step 3 in react native version 0.60 and later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the solution was kinda easy but hard to find.
It was not enough  to run 'react-native.cmd run-android' to rebuild the app.
I had to really unistall the app from the sumulator and reinstall it on the simulator

Answer (score 2):

1- In package.json, add these lines like :

```
"rnpm": {
  "assets": [
    "fonts"
  ]
},
```

2- run : react-native link

3- build your project again by : react-native run-ios (or) react-native run-android

4- you can use fonts in code like :

```
...
export default class myApp extends Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <Text style={styles.myCustomText}>Wow, it looks different.</Text>
    )
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  myCustomText: {
    fontFamily: 'YOUR_CUSTOM_FONT_NAME',
  },

})
```

Comment: sorry for the delay I was on travel. I tried your way but it didnt change anything still no different font displayed

Answer (score 1):

fonts' full names might be different than fonts' filenames. Are you sure you are using the correct full names in your code?

Comment: That's a great hint but i already checked that filename, full-name and in-code stylename are identical including capitalization

Comment: I even doublechecked it on a Mac due some online article that there can be something different as in Windows but turns out it was complete bull so all shown identical under Mac and windows